# FFMPEG : Redirecting Matroska muxed data to socket

Tags: c, sockets, ffmpeg, vlc

I am using FFMPEG library to mux H.264 and AAC frames to Matroska (.mkv) file. I can do that both using command line and C program.

Now, instead of writing the muxed matroska data in to file I want to write these muxed data directly on to socket or pipe. My actual goal is to write a C program that send muxed data to socket and server will receive this muxed data.

I tried using protocol tcp. They are working with the matroska format.
So, My C program is able to send muxed data successfully over socket and server is able to receive this muxed data.

But when I apply ffprobe command over the received file, I am getting duration and bitrate field N/A. and when I tried to play this file with vlc i am unable to seek the file and getting garbage duration.

Below the output of the ffprobe.

```
ffprobe version N-65784-g50a35f0 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 25 2014 12:31:36 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
  libavcodec     56.  0.101 / 56.  0.101
  libavformat    56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Array.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf54.29.104
  Duration: N/A, start: 1412858260.281000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg), 2000x1496 [SAR 1:1 DAR 250:187], 27 fps, 27 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg), 2000x1496 [SAR 1:1 DAR 250:187], 27 fps, 27 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:2: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg), 2000x1496 [SAR 1:1 DAR 250:187], 27 fps, 27 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:3: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg), 2000x1496 [SAR 1:1 DAR 250:187], 27 fps, 27 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
```

As You can see Duration and Bitrate field shows N/A. However I am getting correct startTime.

Any help or advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very unlikely to work because:

- Muxing to a MKV file doesn't mean everything is written to the file sequentially. The MKV Meta Seek block and Cue block (which are needed by players to seek) are probably only updated after the whole file is generated. In fact according to [MKV spec](http://www.matroska.org/technical/diagram/index.html) the Cue block is placed at the end of MKV so it **is** only generated after almost the whole file has been written.
- running ffprobe over a stream won't work for all container formats, because this means ffprobe can't **randomly** access the file content. It may work with files that have meta info placed at its beginning (e.g. qt-faststart processed MP4), but won't work as you expected with formats like MKV.

Comment: @ParthShah please consider accept my answer then ;)

If you really need muxing for streaming, consider using a format that supports streaming, for example FLV. Of course you still can't seek in the stream but at least it will play fine.

Comment: @ParthShah for getting duration I'm afraid you'll have to either a) mux the complete file to MP4, qt-faststart it and then stream it, or b) develop a simple protocol of your own to send the basic meta data such as duration in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

For mp4, its container require to write additional information at the beginning of the file. And this thing can't be done with network Socket. So we can't use MP4 container here.

Comment: Yes...You are correct MP4 container does not support to write muxed data to standard output, because Mp4 container has to move back and forth to write atom.